# Is there support for flattened device tree in Sparc 32 port of the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, devices

We are trying to write a minimal bootloader for booting the linux kernel on a Sparc V8 processor simulator.

From what I understand, the interface between the bootloader and kernel consists of a data structure called the `romvec`. This contains information about the hardware (such as memory size, device information and some function pointers for navigating this data structure) passed from the bootloader to the kernel. However the romvec structure is quite complex, containing pointers to prom functions.

In powerPC and ARM, there exists an option to use a flattened device tree (FDT) structure to pass information about the hardware from the bootloader to the kernel. I was not able to find if support for FDT exists for sparc (32 bit) too.

- **Can the current Sparc-32 port of the linux kernel work with a
  flattened device tree (FDT) structure ?**
- **If yes, how to enable this support?**

Comment: No, in general that isn't how Sparc usually works. FDT is more for devices that don't have expansion buses from what I understand. The romvec structure is where the boot prom stores thing look at how QEMU builds thiers perhaps (openboot prom code). Another place perhaps worth looking is PPC systems that use openboot. U-boot may also have support for the LEON sparc implementation potentially with FDT support... worth a look.